# Date formatting in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, date

I've a date formatted like "Tue Jan 05 11:08:27 +0000 2010" and I want to convert it's format to "yyyy-mm-dd 00:00" in PHP.

How can I do that?

Comment: Really? No one is thinking to mark this as duplicate? We get like 5 Date Formatting questions a day....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

convert it to a PHP date object with strtotime() then output it with date()

**EDIT**

Some more detail; try:

```
$time = strtotime('Tue Jan 05 11:08:27 +0000 2010');
echo date("Y-m-d h:i", $time);
```

Y = 4 digit year
m = 2 digit month (with leading 0)
d = 2 digit month (with leading 0)

h = 12 hour time (leading 0)
i = minutes (with leading 0)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
for all the formatting options

Comment: Make sure to pass $time into the date() function as the second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
$time_string = 'Tue Jan 05 11:08:27 +0000 2010';
$formated_time = date('Y-m-d h:i', strtotime($time_string));
echo $formated_time;
```

Answer (score 0):

[`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) + [`date`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @jocelyn I do concur with your first point, but php's manual pages are probably rather unlikely to change.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Erik, if you want to do it in one line.

Solution

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('Tue Jan 05 11:08:27 +0000 2010'));
```