# date formatting correction

Tags: php

I want to change the look of this date format from:

2012-01-01

to

1 January 2012

My Code:

```
<?php foreach($funds as $fund) { ?>

<li><?php echo $fund['fund']; ?><span class="price"><div align="center" class="h1"><strong><br />
R<?php echo $fund['price']; ?></strong><br />as at <br />
<?php echo $fund['date']; ?></div></span></li>


<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Where's your code to do the conversion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date formatting in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009296/date-formatting-in-php) and a couple hundred more

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = new DateTime('2012-01-01');
echo $date->format('d F Y');
```

[PHP Date Function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Edit

```
<?php foreach($funds as $fund) { ?>
$date = new DateTime($fund['date']);

<li>
    <?php echo $fund['fund']; ?>
    <span class="price">
        <div align="center" class="h1"><br />
            <strong>R<?php echo $fund['price']; ?></strong><br />
            as at <br />
            <?php echo $date->format('d F Y'); ?>
        </div>
    </span>
</li>

<?php } ?>
```

- d = 01 to 31
- F = January through December
- Y = 1999 or 2003

Comment: how and where do i make use of this?

Comment: I played with your formatting a bit too :) I'm not sure why you don't have your span/div merged, IE: <div class="price h1" style="text-align=center;">

Answer (score 1):

try this query

```
select date_format(dateField,'%d %M %Y') from tableName;
```

-- Update

```
$records=mysql_query("select fund,price,date_format(date, '%d %M %Y') as date_formatted from fund");

 foreach( $records as $row)
{
  echo $row['fund'];
  echo $row['price'];
  echo $row['date_formatted'];
}
```

Comment: That appears to be an SQL statement, you might want to specify that it's not php code.

Comment: @BradleyForster His foreach loop appear to be getting Values from Database if you haven't checked.

Comment: It does appear that way. It could also just be an associative array. I wasn't questioning your answer, just that it's not helpful to someone who doesn't know what a "query" is.

Comment: like this:                                                          <?php $funds = query('SELECT * FROM funds;');
select date_format('date, %d %M %Y) from funds';
?>

Comment: @dale `mysql_query("select fund, price, date_format(date, '%d %M %Y')from funds")`

Comment: like this: $funds = query("select fund, price, date_format(date, '%d %M %Y')from funds;");

Answer (score -1):

refer this http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
<?php

$date = '2012-01-01';
echo date("j F Y" , strtotime($date)); 

?>
```

Comment: May I know why this solution is being rewarded a negative rep ?

Comment: why people downvote this...?i execute it..its work perfect